# Create rolling variance from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) which looks like:

```
              A     B         C          D      
date                                       
2014-02-25  2.41  1.0   20712.0  324.90415  
2014-02-26  2.41  1.0   11400.0  324.90415   
2014-02-27  2.40  1.0    4370.0  323.55600   
2014-02-28  2.37  1.0   51943.0  319.51155   
2014-03-03  2.40  1.0   27902.0  323.55600   
:   :       :       :
2015-03-16  2.39  1.0   18059.0  322.20785   
2015-03-17  2.40  1.0   24346.0  323.55600  
2015-03-18  2.35  1.0  344171.0  316.81525     
2015-03-19  2.35  1.0   15247.0  316.81525   
2015-03-20  2.35  1.0   90217.0  316.81525
```

I would like to calculate the rolling variance for Column A for the last 5  dates (2015-03-16 - 2015-03-20) looking back at the last 260 days for each calculation.

I can see to calculate variance I can use `df['A'].var()`.  I could create a new data-frame that would just have the last 260 days but was wondering if there was a more elegant way to calculate the 260 days variance for the last 5 dates in the data-frame for column A?

Comment: Did you look at .rolling() ?

Comment: Thanks, Yes but could not see how to use rolling to only look at the calculating variances for the last 5 dates only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
variance = df.A.rolling(260).var()
```

which gives you variances for the whole data. Then you can do

```
variance[-5:]
```